# My username input is redirecting to about page

Tags: html

```
    <?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lusitana"
</head>

<body>
        <div id="header">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
                <a href = "index.php"</href><h2>Home</h2>
                <a href = "news.php"</href><h2>News</h2>
                <a href = "login.php"</href><h2>Login</h2>
                <a href = "about.php"</href><h2>About</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="login">
        <label for="username">Type the username:</label>
        <input type = "text" name="username" id="username"/>

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the input for typing the username I get redirected to other page of my website 
(about.php)

Can anyone explain why is this happening and give instructions on how to fix?

EDIT: Everything is redirecting to about.php minus the other links from the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <a href = "index.php"</href><h2>Home</h2>
```

Should be

```
 <a href = "index.php"><h2>Home</h2></a>
```

Closing the anchor tag incorrectly

link not closed

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lusitana"

<a href = "index.php"><h2>Home</h2></a>
<a href = "news.php"><h2>News</h2></a>
<a href = "login.php"><h2>Login</h2></a>
<a href = "about.php"><h2>About</h2></a>
```